# How do I customize the post snippet on the homepage of my Blogger blog?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogs

I have a custom theme on Blogger. How do I get the post snippet on the home page to pull certain text in the post instead of pulling from the top?

I tried this in my [post](https://www.melsaywhat.com/2023/01/navigating-video-games-.html)

```
    <div class="post-snippet">
        <p>This is the section of my post that I want to use as the post snippet.</p>
    </div>
```

Along with this in my theme file below the  tag.

```
    <script>
        var snippet = document.querySelector('.post-snippet');
        var post = document.querySelector('.post');
        post.innerHTML = snippet.innerHTML;
    </script>
```

It's not working.

I also tried inserting code next to the below, so as to hide it completely until I can figure this out, but it didn't work either. It did work on a test blog I have using a default Blogger theme, so I think there is some code in the theme that conflicts (or I'm not writing the code correctly).

```
    <data:post.snippet/>
```

```
`<style>
.post-snippet {
    display: none;
}
</style>`
```

Instead of the table of contents showing as the post snippet, I put code around "Video games have become a staple in many children's and teenagers' lives, with 76% of children and teens in the U.S. playing video games. While video games can be a fun and entertaining pastime, it's important for parents to understand the potential risks and benefits. Here are some things parents should consider when it comes to video games, children, and teenagers..."

[screenshot of homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQz6y.png)

The head tag is not written normally, so I think that's the code that's conflicting or not allowing my new code to work.

```
    &lt;head&gt;
```

````
    &lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;```
````

Comment: Hi @melsaywhat! I'm trying to understand your problem. There might be a different way to handle this in your custom theme. Could you share which theme did you use? Maybe you can also contact the creator of the theme.

Regarding `&lt;head&gt;` -- `&lt;` and `&gt;` are just HTML entity for `<` and `>` respectively. More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp).